# c# rotate embedded image

Tags: c#, image, graphics

I have an image that load a .PNG file and then combines it with other graphics I create. The thing is that I need to rotate only the .PNG file, not the whole thing. Picture a speedometer, you have a background image that goes from 0 to 200. That image remains static all the time. Now, on top of it, you have an arrow pointing to your current speed. That's the one I want to rotate.

This is what I have so far. It does display the graphics, but doesn't rotate the .PNG (the arrow)

```
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(500, 280, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        g.Clear(Color.White);

        //this.Arrow = path to the .PNG
        Image i = Image.FromFile(this.Arrow);
        Bitmap a = new Bitmap(i.Width, i.Height);
        Graphics ga = Graphics.FromImage(a);
        a.SetResolution(ga.DpiX, ga.DpiY);

        //It shouldn't rotate having the pivot at the (centre, centre)
        //coordinates, but at the bottom of the image. 
        //The (21, 110) coordinates are right relative to the .PNG file
        ga.TranslateTransform(21, 110);
        ga.RotateTransform(45);   //<--- Not rotating
        ga.DrawImage(i, 0, 0);

        g.DrawImage(i, new Rectangle(new Point(229, 120), new Size(i.Width, i.Height)));

        g.DrawLine(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Aquamarine), 1), 250, 0, 250, 280);
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Aquamarine), 1), 0, 230, 500, 230);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your issue might have to do with the first answer on this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27996037/graphics-rotatetransform-not-working

Comment: It's not working yet. Even tried with the `Matrix()` class and the `.Transform` property, but still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, it is impossible to know for sure what the problem is. There are several possible problems in the code you posted; the most obvious being that you are drawing the image `i` into the `Graphics` object `g`, rather than the image `a` into which you've drawn `i` at a 45-degree rotation.

You will likely get results closer to that desired if you change that program statement to this:

```
g.DrawImage(a, new Rectangle(new Point(229, 120), new Size(a.Width, a.Height)));
```

Other issues include:

- Failing to dispose `ga` and `g` when done with them
- Failing to translate `ga` back to the desired location after the rotation (i.e. you translate to get the rotation of the image to happen around the point (21, 110) of the image, but have left the image translated by that amount after the rotation, which may not be what you want
- Using positive offsets for the previously-mentioned translation

Because of these issues (and possibly others), I don't think the above change will result in exactly the desired output, but at least you will see some evidence of rotation.

While your error does not seem to be that which I've addressed in my answer to [the question commenter Keith M mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27996037/graphics-rotatetransform-not-working), I do think you would benefit from reading the code example there, as it does basically the same thing you are trying to do here.

Comment: The good minimal code example IS posted. That is what I'm using.

Comment: Please read the link I provided, so that you understand what is meant by _"good, minimal, **complete** code example"_. "Minimal" is a necessary but not sufficient condition. Your example needs to be complete as well. Also, please consider reading the answer and trying the suggested solution before dismissing it.